# is there a way to find the path for mongo database that I have created

Tags: mongodb, dockerfile

I built a mongo database and now I'm learning about docker and I want to containerize it. Within the dockerfile configuration I need to provide the path for my created db and I don't know how to find it.

I have tried with chatgpt but it does not help

Comment: Post your `Dockerfile` or `docker-compose`. You will need to export your current database with `mongodump` and then restore it to the docker-instance with `mongorestore`. Show what you have tried so far (code) in a [**Minimal, Reproducible Example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and be specific about which part is giving you trouble. Take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about what's on-topic in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).